# VBA: How to fix cells positions in the OFFSET function

Tags: vba, rows, offset, fixed, dynamic-columns

I would like how this is coded:

```
OFFSET($F$52, 0, ($D342 - $D$342),1,1)
```

Since the cells positions are not the same, to represent cell D342 I will be using for instance Cells(300 + i, 5 + j).

I want to know how to fix cells using VBA code:
 i)  To fix the row
 ii) To fix the column 
 iii) To fix the row and the column

Thanks :)

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Unlike Excel formulas, VBA offers you the possibility to define *variables*. You can fix them, change them or do with them whatever suits your application.

Comment: @A.S.H., if want to fix a row, i want to know how to code to represent D$342. If I want to fix a column, i want to know how to code $D342. If i want to fix both, then how do I write the code for $D$342 That's what I am asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a range and you want to insert its address in a formula, you can use its `.Address`. This property is very flexible and permits you to control many things, including and most importantly, whether you want things to be absolute (fixed) or relative (movable when copying).

For the sake of your problem you can use the parameters `RowAbsolute` and `ColumnAbsolute` of the `.Address method`. For example, `Cells(300 + i, 5 + j).Address(RowAbsolute=False)`. Remember that the default value for these parameters is `True`.

The following code snippet will tell you how to do so, explanation are included.

```
Sub TestUsingAddress()
   Dim r As Range
   Set r = Sheet1.Cells(3, 4) ' (D3)

   ' You can control the parameters RowAbsolute and ColumnAbsolute
   Debug.Print r.address                        ' $D$3 (default)
   Debug.Print r.address(ColumnAbsolute:=False) ' D$3
   Debug.Print r.address(RowAbsolute:=False)    ' $D3
   Debug.Print r.address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False) ' D3

   'and you can get the sheet's name with the address using the External parameter
   Debug.Print r.address(external:=True) ' [SOTest.xlsm]Sheet1!$D$3

   ' You can also get R1C1 format using the ReferenceStyle Parameter
   Debug.Print r.address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) ' R3C4. default format is xlA1
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @A.S.H for your help!